# Rails - unable to convert simple select to chosen field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**What I have**

I have a simple select field on a view, its not part of any form, selecting any option sends a remote request to the route.

There are a bunch of applications in a view listed in table and each application has this dropdown which user can use to assign a tag to the application. The code of this `select_tag` is as following.

```
<%= select_tag 'application_tag',
   options_from_collection_for_select(HiringTag.order(:name), :id, :name, application.tag),
   prompt: "Assign a tag to the application",
   class: "form-control input-block-level chzn-select",
   id: "hiring_tag_dropdown",
   data: {
     remote: true,
     url: "applications/"+application.id.to_s+"/assign_tags",
     method: 'post'
   }
%>
```

Right now this works fine as it is and tag is being assigned to the application.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to convert this `select_tag` to multi select field using `collection_select` and the gem I am using is `gem 'chosen-rails'`. Looking at the documentation and several other blog articles it seemed like a straight forward job but I just cant get the field to appear the way it should. This is what I have done.

```
<%= collection_select :application_id, :application_tag, HiringTag.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {include_blank: true, multiple: true, class: 'form-control input-block-level chzn-select'} %>
```

This is what the field looks like in view

[image]

and this is how i am expecting it to look like

[image]

I also added the javascript part but that did not help either

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
```

**Question**

What am i doing wrong here :)